# Creating samples of unit squares with different set of points in R

Tags: r

I am going to create, for example, 100 points on a unit square and I need to create 1000 unit squares with a different set of 100 points. Points should be created as

```
x = runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
y = runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
```

I thought to create `x[i]` where i is from `1 to 1000` as

```
x=NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
  x[i]=runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
}
```

but it did not work. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign NULL to x and then use indices, use `x=vector("numeric",1000)`, also you cannot assign 100 values in one index of a vector, maybe you want a matrix `x=matrix(NA,nrow=100,ncol=1000)`.

Or even better `matrix(rnorm(100*1000),nrow=100,ncol=1000)`.